Tcolorbox without the body (just the title)
With the tcolorbox package, I want to print just the title (and not the body). I have it almost working in the MWE  below, with a few issues:

For the Title Only Style, I have hard coded height=16.5pt. This works for a single line title, but won't work if the title takes up more than one line.

The arc at the top left and top right seems to be slightly different when I have only the title.


Notes:

I do need each part on its own page so that the title (without the body) can easily be extracted.  Thus the use of \begin{preview}...\end{preview}.

The MWE  yields:

Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6cm]{geometry}

\tcbset{MyTitleStyle/.style={%
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=yellow,
    colbacktitle=gray,
    colbacktitle=olive!50!white,
    titlerule=0.4pt,% width of rule below title
    titlerule style={brown, line width=0.5pt},
    enhanced,
    %% ---------------------------------------------------------------
}}
\tcbset{Title Only Style/.style={%
        %bottomtitle=0pt,
        height=16.5pt,%% <--- This length needs to be computed
        sharp corners=south,
        bottomrule=0pt,
        %titlerule=0.4pt,% width of rule below title
        upperbox=invisible,
}}
\NewEnviron{MyTcolorbox}[1]{% 
    % #1 = Title
    \begin{preview}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
        MyTitleStyle,
        title={\raggedright#1},
        Title Only Style,
    ]%
        %%\BODY Do NOT need body when only showing title
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \end{preview}
    \begin{preview}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[%
        MyTitleStyle,
        title={\raggedright#1},%
    ]%
        \BODY
    \end{tcolorbox}%
    \end{preview}
}%

\begin{document}
    \begin{MyTcolorbox}{My One Line Title}%
        Body 1.
    \end{MyTcolorbox}%
    \begin{MyTcolorbox}{My Two Line Long Title}%
        Body 2.
    \end{MyTcolorbox}%
\end{document}


You could use the attach boxed title to top option to make the title its own box:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\usepackage[paperwidth=6cm]{geometry}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{
    colframe=red!75!black,
    colback=yellow,
    colbacktitle=gray,
    colbacktitle=olive!50!white,
    titlerule=0.4pt,% width of rule below title
    titlerule style={brown, line width=0.5pt},
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top,
    frame hidden,
    interior hidden,
    lowerbox=ignored,
    top=-\baselineskip,
    title={#1},
    before upper=\tcblower,
    boxed title style={outer arc=1.3mm}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mybox}{My One Line Title}%
        Body 1. Body 1. Body 1. Body 1. Body 1. Body 1. Body 1. Body 1.
    \end{mybox}%
    \begin{mybox}{My Two Line Long Title}%
        Body 2.
    \end{mybox}%
\end{document}



@PeterGrill Are you extracting the title as text or as image?

Extracting it as a pdf to be overlaid on the full version, so that the title does not scroll, when the page is scrolled. So, I do need both with and without the title.

Besides the color of the rule below the title changing, the issue of the top left and right corners being slight different is still there. Wondering if that is some sort of bug in `tcolorbox'?

@PeterGrill I get the exact same colour for the rule below the title as the rest https://i.sstatic.net/KniX96fG.png

Compare the rule below the title in my image in the question (which is brown) and yours (which is red). Easier to see if you keep the same structure I had with the preview environment.

@PeterGrill Use an overlay to draw a line in whatever colour you like

It is already specified with titlerule style={brown, line width=0.5pt}. Are you suggesting not to use that?

@PeterGrill I'm suggesting to draw in an overlay as a separate title box does not use the titlerule.

You could just use a tikzpicture.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

%\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}% not familiar with package
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6cm]{geometry}

\tikzset{Title Only Style/.style={%
    draw=red!75!black,
    thick,
    fill=olive!50!white,
    text=white,
    font=\bfseries,
    rounded corners,
    text width={\dimexpr \linewidth-0.666em-1.6pt}% 2* inner sep + 2* thickness
}}

\newcommand{\MyTcolorbox}[1]{% 
    % #1 = Title
    \par\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[Title Only Style] (temp) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}\par
}%

\begin{document}
    \MyTcolorbox{My One Line Title}
    \MyTcolorbox{My Two Line Long Title}
\end{document}


